# TypeScript React: How to pass all props to child function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript React. Need help in converting the following React JS code to Typescript React. Am really confused on how to pass the props to child function.

React JS

blog.js

```
    import contentarea from './contentarea.js';
    export default function Blog() {
    return (
    <contentarea wid={12} hei={6}>
    </contentarea>
    );
    }
```

contentarea.js

```
   import PropTypes from "prop-types";
   export default function contentarea(props) {
   const { children, ...rest } = props;
   return (
   <contentarea  {...rest}>
   {children}
   </contentarea>
   );
   }    

   contentarea.propTypes = {
   children: PropTypes.node
   };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use React’s Context. Go through from this url for know more about it : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thanks Bhawana..Will go through it...

Comment: React component names must be capitalized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not typescript specific, if my understanding of your question is right, you want the wid and hei to be passed to component in the "children" to do so you can wrap it under a HOC

```
const PropWrapper = (WrappedComponent, givenProps) => {
const hocComponent = ({ ...props }) => <WrappedComponent {...props} {...givenProps} />

hocComponent.propTypes = {
}

return hocComponent}
```

And use to before you render children

```
<contentarea>{PropWrapper(children, rest)}</contentarea>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Nightraiser! This answer is very much close to the query. Will try it out and update here.

Comment: Sure @NightRaiser, but I had to stall this work for some time. As soon as I resume it and try the solution, will mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.